# Magento 2: Data migration tool installation

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I am going to migrate data from M1(CE) to M2(EE). I have a module of data migration tool. I placed it in `vendor/magento` directory.

Module does not install **when i run magento upgrade command** as i do not find its entry in setup_module table.

Am i installing it in a wrong way?

I do not want to install using composer.

**Any help?**

Answer (score 0):

you are not installing module correct way as you have placed in vendor/magento directory .

Put the extension inside **app/code** folder and then run setup upgrade command. and then check it would be registered automatically in setup_module table.

All the extensions remains inside app->code folder in magento 2.

for e.g app/code/vendor_name/module_name etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should install composer.

*I don't thought that without   composer ,the application will run .*

***Regarding,data migration tool, you donot need to install module enable command also setup update command .***